# how to structure my training data for instruction fine-tuning of Llama?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to do instruction-based fine-tuning of the `LlaMa-7B` model and am slightly confused now about how to feed data to the model during fine-tuning.

The task is to generate high level business description of tables given the table name and it's column names. Example for that can be:

```
prompt: 'Provide high level business description for the given table'
input: 'Table name FACT_RSTDD containing columns MEMBERSHIP_DT, FIRST_NAME, .., PLACE, '
output: 'The table contains information about insurance members and their demographics...'
```

How should I construct my input_ids and labels

A) I should treat it as a modelling task and generate a consolidated prompt comprising prompt, input and output and feed it to the network while fine-tuning (treating it as a language modelling task). In this case, the input_ids and label would be the same as the consolidated prompt.

B) Or I should create an input comprising of the prompt and input data while the label consists of the output data? (Treating it as a translation task)

Which approach is better suited in this case? Any insights will be helpful.

Comment: I found a link that may have some useful info, the prompt, completion JSON looks similar. https://www.mlexpert.io/machine-learning/tutorials/alpaca-fine-tuning